# Is it useful to delete entry objects before leaving the function?

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, del

Python has an embedded garbage collector, but it is good to explicit write command gc.collect() before leaving the function. Before that, it is welcome to delete the local variable with del command. What is not clear to me is whether the input variables / objects that the function has received should also be deleted?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it's good to call gc.collect before leaving each function? It most certainly is *not*.

Comment: `del` just decrements the reference count of the object referred to by the local variable, which happens automatically when the variable goes out of scope. Explicitly writing `del ...` just clutters your code for no benefit.

Comment: None of these things are necessary. You almost never need to `del` a variable in a function, and almost certainly, you do not have to use `gc.collect`, and you shouldn't, where did you get the idea that it is good? In any case it will only affect the cyclic garbage collector, which deals with reference cycles, every other object is automatically managed by using a reference counting mechanism in the CPython runtime.

Comment: The idea came by solving real problems in real life, where wiping out unnecessary objects and calling garbage colector before return saves a lot of memory. I claim to be very helpful from your own experience. Some obviously did not have such experiences, but that does not mean that it is not true.

Comment: Of course I'm not going to delete something inside a function that is often called. :-)

Answer (score -1):

In general, no -- do not clean up.  By forcing garbage collection when not needed, you're wasting execution time ... a *lot* of execution time.  The run-time system is written to perform GC as needed.

If you know better than the run-time system -- if you know when to call GC to significantly improve your program's performance, then go ahead and call it as needed.  Asking the question shows that you do not have that knowledge.  Most of us don't, and most of those who do, know better than to try to out-perform the built-in functions.

Do not `del` your local objects.  If you make an error in doing this, and accidentally delete an external object, then your function will damage the program overall.